# Basic: How to use PATCH Method User Model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have problem with using PATCH Method User Model in Django Rest Framework. Hope your guy helps and save my time.

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^account/edit/$', UserDetailAPIView.as_view({'patch': 'edit'}))
]
```

**Views.py:**

```
class UserDetailAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['PATCH'])
        def edit(self, request):
           user_obj = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
           serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(user_obj, data=request.data, partial=True)
           if serializer.is_valid():
              serializer.save()
              return Response(serializer.data)
           return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Serializer:**

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        ]
```

Error:

```
It's not partial update. It update all fields with let it blank.
```

Comment: Can you add request body?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner how to add it, bro

Comment: Just show what data do you send which rise this error.

Comment: It comes no error. It just not update partially but totally. I filled `email` and leave it blank `first_name` and `last_name`. It save `first name` and `last_name` with no data. It must be not save `first_name` and `last_name`

Comment: You need to pass only email: {'emai':'test@test.com'} first_name and last_name key should not be included. Did you tried it?

Comment: That's it. Thank you. Dump question :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `patch` you need to pass only updated field to your API. For example to update email you need to send this: `{'emai':'test@test.com'}`. In other word you need not to provide all serializer's fied.